# Too many open files in system SocketException in .net core API / cloud run

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, socketexception, google-cloud-run

I have written a .net core API that is containerized and running in Cloud Run. My api gets calls each time a file gets created in GCS bucket (once per file) and it processes the file and writes out new files in another bucket. At the moment I am uploading about 50-80 files every minute to that source bucket.  In the logs, I am seeing a lot of these errors.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Too many open files in system ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Too many open files in system at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) at System.Net.Sockets.DualSocketMultipleConnectAsync..ctor(SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectAsync(SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am also seeing in the cloud run metrics that there are a lot more 4xx responses than 2xx responses. And for some reason my charges for JAN 31 were about $10 for the day, whereas for yesterday was hardly $2. I have a feeling a lot of files are now just getting dropped with 4xx and not getting processed. I will do more investigation, but how can I find out what is exactly causing 4xx errors. And how to address the above error? I have read some articles about changing linux system settings to allow for more files but I am not sure where to make those changes in my .net core api running inside cloud run?

Comment: Are you closing the files after writing them in bucket? Are you deleting them?

Comment: Are you getting any out of memory errors?

Comment: Grrr, I had older code running that did not have code for deleting files. I think this may be it.

Comment: Let me know it that was the issue? @AIK DO

Comment: Hi @AIKDO, if the older code you had running was indeed the issue, it would be extremely helpful if you could post an answer on the steps you followed to solve your issue for other community users who may face the same issue. Otherwise, keep me posted using **@sllopis** tag.